# Yellow trianlges on every reference in asp .net project

Tags: asp.net, reference, solution

I have a new project for a new job. The project will not build on my computer. It has yellow triangles under every reference that isn't a project in the solution. It even has a yellow triangle for microsoft.csharp. I have been digging and tried many things online and on stack overflow. Anyone have an ideas, would love to keep this job. Thanks.

Comment: Uhm, fix the references?

Answer (score 1):

you need to restore the nuget packages

Answer (score 1):

Like @Dai and @Michael suggest, you need to re-install the references. I just provide the detail.

There are many ways to do it. This is what I usually do.

Step 1: [Enable NuGet package restore](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/package-restore#migrating-to-automatic-restore). 
[image]

Step 2: go to the `packages` folder of your project: C:\path\your project\packages\

Step 3: delete everything in that folder

Step 4: open the project again in VS and **Build** the project (**Build > Build Solution**). NuGet will download and re-install all required packages

Answer (score 0):

1. try to do a build first
2. if that doesn't fix it then restore the nuget packages
3. if that doesn't work then clear your local nuget cache and rebuild the project